# Display a message after file upload in Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to display a message from “return json(message)” of action in jquery dialog after posting its form. I tried with the following, everything works fine, but return JsonResult triggering Save/Open prompt instead of OnSuccess call with Ajax.BeginForm.

Partial View:

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveDetails", "FileManage", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnFileUploadSuccess" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "myForm" }))
    {
         <input id="fuMyFile" type="file" name="files" />
         <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
<div id="dialogboxWin" style="display: none; padding: 8px 15px;">
    <div id="dvWindow"></div>
</div>
```

Following is the jQuery code:

```
  $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {

            $("#dvWindow").html("Are you sure to submit?");
            $("#dialogboxWin").dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 400,
                autoOpen: true,
                title: 'Confirmation',
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $('#myForm).submit();
                    },
                    "No": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

    return false;
});

function OnFileUploadSuccess(data) {
    alert(data.Message);
 }
```

Controller Action Method:

```
 [HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveDetails(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

        bool isSaved = File Saving & Some DB operations

        return Json(new
        {
            Result = isSaved
            Message = (isSaved)?"Saved Successfully." : "Failed"
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are submitting the form you don't get the message returned from the action.You can save the message you want to show in some session variable and check whether the session variable contains any value or not in document ready of the page and show message accordingly.